# Gitlab: missing pages artifacts

Tags: docker, gitlab

My gitlab page can't proceed to deployment eventhough build passed says artifacts are missing. I'm currently following the tutorial from https://about.gitlab.com/features/pages/
and using template https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html

Please see screenshots:
[screenshot of job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95RtH.png)
[screenshot of compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKjYJ.png)

You can checkout my repo here: https://gitlab.com/jairus.jsx/portfolio
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

to all experiencing the same error just update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` :)

```yaml
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

this way, your public folder gets updated everytime you build

Comment: Thanks! Saved me some time, I deleted the step accidentally :)

Comment: A little note on why this works: `missing pages artifacts` appears if GitLab knows it is time to deploy, but refers to the missing `artifacts` section (nothing to deploy is a reasonable reason to raise an error).

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is unclear: what does "update your `.gitlab-ci.yml`" mean? What should I update? In my case, the issue what that the directory in which the script wrote the HTML didn’t match the one expected in `artifacts.paths`.